# how to do custom keras layer matrix multiplication

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

Layers:

- Input shape `(None,75)`
- Hidden layer 1 - shape is `(75,3)`
- Hidden layer 2 - shape is `(3,1)`

For the last layer, the output must be calculated as `( (H21*w1)*(H22*w2)*(H23*w3))`, where `H21,H22,H23` will be the outcome of Hidden layer 2, and `w1,w2,w3` will be constant weight which are not trainable. So how to write a lambda function for the above outcome

```
def product(X):
    return X[0]*X[1]

keras_model = Sequential()
keras_model.add(Dense(75, 
input_dim=75,activation='tanh',name="layer1" ))
keras_model.add(Dense(3 ,activation='tanh',name="layer2" ))
keras_model.add(Dense(1,name="layer3"))
cross1=keras_model.add(Lambda(lambda x:product,output_shape=(1,1)))([layer2,layer3])
print(cross1)
```

> NameError: name 'layer2' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the functional API model

```
inputs = Input((75,))                                         #shape (batch, 75)
output1 = Dense(75, activation='tanh',name="layer1" )(inputs) #shape (batch, 75)
output2 = Dense(3 ,activation='tanh',name="layer2" )(output1) #shape (batch, 3)
output3 = Dense(1,name="layer3")(output2)                     #shape (batch, 1)

cross1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] * x[1])([output2, output3])    #shape (batch, 3)

model = Model(inputs, cross1)
```

Please notice that the shapes are totally different from what you expect.

Comment: Iam new to keras...then how to write for my expectation.

Input shape (None,75)
Hidden layer 1 - shape is (75,3)
Hidden layer 2 - shape is (3,1)
For the last layer, the output must be calculated as ( (H21*w1)*(H22*w2)*(H23*w3)), where H21,H22,H23 will be the outcome of Hidden layer 2, and w1,w2,w3 will be constant weight which are not trainable. So how to write a lambda function for the above outcome

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to do it via a customized layer instead of the `Lambda` layer. Why? A customized will give you more freedom to do stuffs, and it is also more transparent in terms of viewing your desired weights. More precisely, if you do it through `Lambda` layer, the constant weight will not be saved as a part of the model, but it will if you use a customized layer.

## Here is an example

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
import numpy as np 


class MyLayer(Layer) :
    # see https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/
    def __init__(self, 
                 w_vec=None, 
                 allow_training=False,
                 **kwargs) :
        self._w_vec = w_vec
        assert allow_training or (w_vec is not None), \
            "ERROR: non-trainable w_vec must be initialized"
        self.allow_training = allow_training
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        return
    def build(self, input_shape) :
        batch_size, num_feats = input_shape
        self.w_vec = self.add_weight(shape=(1, num_feats),
                                     name='w_vec',
                                     initializer='uniform', # <- use your own preferred initializer
                                     trainable=self.allow_training,)
        if self._w_vec is not None :
            # predefined w_vec
            assert self._w_vec.shape[1] == num_feats, \
                "ERROR: initial w_vec shape mismatches the input shape"
            # set it to the weight
            self.set_weights([self._w_vec])  # <- set weights to the supplied one
        super().build(input_shape)
        return
    def call(self, x) :
        # Given:
        #   x = [H21, H22, H23]
        #   w_vec = [w1, w2, w3]
        # Step 1: output elem_prod
        #   elem_prod = [H21*w1, H22*w2, H23*w3]
        elem_prod = x * self.w_vec
        # Step 2: output ret
        #   ret = (H21*w1) * (H22*w2) * (H23*w3)
        ret = K.prod(elem_prod, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        return ret
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape) :
        return (input_shape[0], 1)

def make_test_cases(w_vec=None, allow_training=False):
    x = Input(shape=(75,))
    y = Dense(75, activation='tanh', name='fc1')(x)
    y = Dense(3, activation='tanh', name='fc2')(y)
    y = MyLayer(w_vec, allow_training, name='core')(y)
    y = Dense(1, name='fc3')(y)
    net = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y, name='{}-{}'.format( 'randomInit' if w_vec is None else 'assignInit',
                                                          'trainable' if allow_training else 'nontrainable'))
    print(net.name)
    print(net.layers[-2].get_weights()[0])
    print(net.summary())
    return net
```

And you may run the following test cases to see the differences (pay attention to the first and the last lines in the print out, which gives you the initial values and the number of constant parameters, respectively)

### a. Constant weights, non-trainable

```
m1 = make_test_cases(w_vec=np.arange(3).reshape([1,3]), allow_training=False)
```

will give you

```
assignInit-nontrainable [[0. 1. 2.]]
_________________________________________________________________  
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param # 

=================================================================  
input_4 (InputLayer)         (None, 75)                0         
_________________________________________________________________  
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 75)                5700      
_________________________________________________________________  
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 3)                 228       
_________________________________________________________________  
core (MyLayer)               (None, 1)                 3         
_________________________________________________________________  
fc3 (Dense)                  (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================  
Total params: 5,933  
Trainable params: 5,930  
Non-trainable params: 3
_________________________________________________________________
```

### b. Constant weights, trainable

```
m2 = make_test_cases(w_vec=np.arange(3).reshape([1,3]), allow_training=True)
```

will give you

```
assignInit-trainable    [[0. 1. 2.]]
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         (None, 75)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 75)                5700      
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 3)                 228       
_________________________________________________________________
core (MyLayer)               (None, 1)                 3         
_________________________________________________________________
fc3 (Dense)                  (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,933
Trainable params: 5,933
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

### c. Random weights, trainable

```
m3 = make_test_cases(w_vec=None, allow_training=True)
```

will give you

```
randomInit-trainable [[ 0.02650297 -0.02010062 -0.03771694]]
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         (None, 75)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 75)                5700      
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 3)                 228       
_________________________________________________________________
core (MyLayer)               (None, 1)                 3         
_________________________________________________________________
fc3 (Dense)                  (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,933
Trainable params: 5,933
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

## Final remark

I will say it is unclear which case may work better in advance for your problem, but trying all three sounds like a good plan.

Comment: w_vec = [1, 1, 1]...sir can i fix the constant weights directly

Comment: Of course you can, just set something like `m1 = make_test_cases(w_vec=np.array([[1,1,1]]), allow_training=False)`

Comment: def forward_prop(params)
 '''some code number of layers and neurons where last layer gives result as output'''
 exp_scores = np.exp(result)
 probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)
 N = 150  # Number of samples
 corect_logprobs = -np.log(probs[range(N), y])
 loss = np.sum(corect_logprobs) / N
 return loss

Comment: This computes for the forward propagation of the neural network, as well as the loss.so how to write in keras